# Rails best way to change relation from model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this schema.

[image]

And I would like to change the relationship as follows.

[image]

I am not sure what is the best way to do it without breaking anything.

Reverting or rollback the `create_varieties_wines` migration ?

```
class CreateVarietiesWines < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :varieties_wines do |t|
      t.references :wine, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :variety, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```